# Angular nested routes with hard-coded component in the "middle" of a route

Tags: angular, angular-routing

This question has a Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-imdhhc. The application has the following component hierarchy

```
app
  home
    foo
      bar
        baz
```

- `app` renders `home` using `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`
- `home` renders `foo` using `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`
- `foo` renders `bar` using `<app-bar></app-bar>`

This works as expected

- https://angular-ivy-imdhhc.stackblitz.io renders `app`
- https://angular-ivy-imdhhc.stackblitz.io/home renders `home`
- https://angular-ivy-imdhhc.stackblitz.io/home/foo renders `foo` and `bar` because `<app-bar></app-bar>` is hard-coded

[image]

However, while `bar` is rendered, its child component is not. The `bar` routing module defines a nested route to render the `baz` component.

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: BarComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '**',
        component: BazComponent,
      },
    ],
  },
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class BarRoutingModule {}
```

A wildcard is used to try and get `baz` to render, but this doesn't work. I guess this has something to do with the hard-coded `<app-bar></app-bar>` in `foo`.

Should this work? If not, is there a way to achieve this without having to "chain" `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` at every level of the component hierarchy?

**More detail on what I'm trying to achieve.**

Imagine the application hierarchy was

```
app
  home
    foo
      bar
        baz
        qux
        quux
        ...
    not-foo
  not-home
```

Routing is needed to provide the following top-level paths

- `/home` and `/not-home`
- `/home/foo` and `/home/not-foo`

However, once `/home/foo` has been rendered, `bar` must always be rendered and `bar` should NOT be in the URL (path). Thereafter, the following routes are needed

- `/home/foo/baz`
- `/home/foo/qux`
- `/home/foo/quux`

Comment: Your child route is never hit because bar is already a match. If baz doesn’t need a route, the router is not the correct way. What is your expectation? Baz belongs in bar as a component when it’s not routed right?

Comment: Correct. There could be other components alongside baz that could get rendered depending on the path/url. But they all have a common parent (bar)

Comment: I mean.. adding /whatever should render baz if there is a router outlet in bar..

Comment: It's not clear to me what URL and `path` is required to render `baz`. For example, if the URL ended with `/home/foo/whatever`, what `path` should be added to `bar.routing.module.ts` to render `BazComponent`?

Answer (score 0):

In the *bar* routing module, you can enforce the *baz* component to render by adding the path match under children for *bar* as follows:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'bar',
    component: BarComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: ':anyother',
        component: BazComponent,
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

The URL will route with any segment after */home/foo*. So */home/foo/anypath* will render *bazComponent*.

Also, remove the tag

```
<app-bar></app-bar>
```

from the *foo* component HTML as the routing is controlled from the routing module for *bar*.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewHalil, I implemented your suggestion in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hvsg13. The `/home/foo` path works, but `/home/foo/bar` does not render the `foo` component.